# How to stop Stream to evaluate next element and get accumulated result in a functional way

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have this code and I want to let Stream to stop iteration and also get the accumulated result. Basically, the iteration is based on errorLimit number

```
sealed trait Ele

case class FailureEle() extends Ele
case class SuccessEle() extends Ele

type EitherResult = Either[IndexedSeq[Ele], Seq[FailureEle]]

 def parse(process: Process[Task, Ele], errorLimit: Int): EitherResult = {

  val errorAccumulator = new ListBuffer[FailureEle]
  val taskProcess = process.map(t => {
    t match {
      case x: FailureEle => errorAccumulator += x
      case _ => 
    }
    t
  }).takeWhile(_ => !(errorAccumulator.size == errorLimit))

    val voSeq = taskProcess.runLog.run

    if (errorAccumulator.isEmpty) {
      Left(voSeq)
    } else {
      Right(errorAccumulator)
    }

}
val result = Seq(FailureEle(), SuccessEle(), FailureEle(), SuccessEle(), SuccessEle(), FailureEle(), SuccessEle())

val adaptor = new SeqAdaptor[Ele](result)

val process: Process[Task, Ele] = Process
  .repeatEval(Task {adaptor.next()}).takeWhile(t => !t.shouldStop).map(_.get)

parse(process, 1).isRight //no SuccessEle will be iterated
parse(process, 2).isRight //only one SuccessEle will be iterated
parse(process, 3).isRight //the last one SuccessEle will not be iterated
```

It is working, but there are several issues that I want to refactor the parse method to be more functional:

- ListBuffer is an imperative way
- takeWhile condition has no logic to check current element, it is still using ListBuffer result

so I wonder is there a tail recursion way to replace the imperative way by using ListBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

`scan` may not be better enough, but works

```
     sealed trait Ele
      case class FailureEle(e: Throwable) extends Ele
      case class SuccessEle(r: String) extends Ele

      def parse(p: Process[Task, Ele], error: Int): Process[Task, (Seq[SuccessEle],   Seq[FailureEle])] = {
            p.scan(Seq[SuccessEle]() -> Seq[FailureEle]()) { (r, e) =>
              val (s, f) = r
              e match {
                case fail: FailureEle =>
                  s  -> (f :+ fail)
                case succ: SuccessEle =>
                  (s :+ succ) -> f
              }
            }.dropWhile { case (succ, fail) => fail.size < error }.take(1)
          }

        def test() {
            def randomFail = {
              val nInt =  scala.util.Random.nextInt()
              println("getting" +  nInt)
              if(nInt % 5 == 0 )
                FailureEle(new Exception("fooo"))
              else
                SuccessEle(nInt.toString)
            }
            val infinite = Process.repeatEval(Task.delay(randomFail))
            val r = parse(infinite, 3).runLast.run
            println(r)
}
```